# Understanding the definition of differentiable submanifold

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, definition, submanifold

A subset $M \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is called a smooth k-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $k \leq n$, if any point $x \in M$ has a neighborhood $O_x$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ in which $M$ is described as follows

- There exists a smooth vector-function $$F:O_x \to \mathbb{R}^{n-k}, \text{  } \text{  rank } \frac{dF}{dx}|_q=n-k $$
  such that $O_x \cap M = F^{-1}(0)$

When we ask that $\text{  rank } \frac{dF}{dx}|_q=n-k$, what are we trying to say, what is the need for this in the definition?

Comment: This is because of the local normal form of submersion. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submersion_(mathematics)

F^{-1}(0) can be deformed to locally look like a $k$-linear subspace $\mathbb{R}^k \times \{ 0 \}^{n-k} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: Since $F: O_x \subseteq \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^{n-k}$, the maximum possible rank for $F$ at any point is $\min \{n, n-k\} = n-k$. So it is the same thing as asking each derivative $DF(x)$ to be surjective. For $k =1$, this is the same as asking $\nabla F(x) \neq 0$, which you should be familiar with.